# How to accept to a api access by webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing on webpack-dev-server.
When I try to access http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2848756&appid={api_key}, I couldn't access and I can see a this log.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id={api_key}. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

I try to set on webpack.config.js. it's like bellow setting.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: 'dist',
    inline: true,
    hot:true,
    port: 8081,
    proxy: {
    '/**': {
    target: 'http://api.openweathermap.org',
    secure: false
  }
}
```

But It still doesn't work. do you know how to resolve it?
Let me know about that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `headers` property from your `axios.create()` call, they don't make sense (the `Access-Control-*` ones are response headers, not request headers, and `withCredentials` is an option, not a header) and may confuse the browser into thinking it needs to perform a CORS preflight that doesn't look like it's supposed by the OpenWeather API server:

```
const apiClient = API_URL => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL         : API_URL,
    timeout         : 100000,
    withCredentials : 'true'
  });
};
```

Comment: I see. when I try to use your setting, it had another error, then, I try to use bellow setting.
`const forecastApiClient = () => {
  return axios.create ( {
    baseURL: FORECAST_API_URL,
    timeout: 100000,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8081',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    },
    withCredentials: true
  });
};`

but it has another error. I write error next comment.

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

I set my webpack-dev-server url is `http://localhost:8081`. I don't know why it can't access.

Comment: Try removing `withCredentials` as well, it may not even be required. To be clear: don't send _any_ headers in your request.

Comment: Oh, when I remove `all headers` and `withCredentials`, I can resolve it.Thanks @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

You will have to Register on open weather API website after that you will get API key which you will have to use for calling API

in your case while calling

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2848756&appid={api_key}

please insert api_key after registration in above call.
suppose after registration you get api_key as =xxxxxxx

use it in above call
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2848756&appid=xxxxxxx

then and then you will receive data in JSON response.
for more information visit

https://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: Thanks, to be honest, I already got api_key and set it.
When I access this url on browser, I can access. but I can't access it on web pack-dev-server. 
Perhaps, Do I make mistake axios setting?
My axios setting is bellow.
 `const apiClient = (API_URL) => {
  return axios.create ( {
    baseURL: API_URL,
    timeout: 100000,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
          'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
      'xhrFields':{
        'withCredentials': 'true'
      }
    }
  });
};`

Comment: Generally, for security reason access to external APIs are blocked from the server.
Go to your server  and open console and write telnet command eg. telnet http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2848756&appid={api_key} if it is not connecting means access to above api is blocked

Comment: @PawanPatil if it was blocked, it wouldn't return a 405 status response